# How long do deleted questions last i nthe deleted section?

Tags: stack, overflow

I was wondering how long deleted questions will stay in the deleted area, I am hoping they stay forever or at-least a good year but i cant find it anywhere on the internet. Does anyone know?

I have deleted one post I made and I haven't been able to try anything as there is nothing to try i just need answers if possible. Thank you.

Comment: This question doesn’t belong on Stack Overflow, but on its meta site. Please move your question to [meta].

Comment: There's no mention of it or intention of removal yet. It will be considered when becomes a problem

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of it or intention of removal yet. It will be considered when becomes a problem